# Entity Framework Core seed data

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

So I have a Entity Framework Core first database and a .Net Core application.

I want to add Seed Data to it when creating the database. I know the FluentAPI has the HasData method but that is not what i am looking for.

When the database gets created I want to create a user with a random generated password (that is different every time) that will be saved on a file in the server.

I can't use the HasData method because then it will create the same password everytime.

So my question is: Is there a way, other than the HasData method, to add Seed data to a Entity Framework Core Code First database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes! There is a way! You can do as follows:

```
public static class DatabaseInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize(YourDbContext dbContext)
    {
        dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        if (!dbContext.Users.Any())
        {
            // Write you necessary to code here to insert the User to database and save the the information to file.

        }

    }
}
```

The in the `Configure` method of the `Startup` class as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, YourDbContext dbContext)
{
   // other configurations
   ..............

   DatabaseInitializer.Initialize(dbContext);

   ..............
   // other configurations
}
```

`Initialize` method will be called only once during the application start up.

Comment: I didn't see ASP.NET Core mentioned anywhere.

Comment: My point is the question author didn't mention ASP.NET Core anywhere in the question while your code is designed to be used within ASP.NET Core. But probably you guessed it right. Nevermind.

Comment: Oh! Understood! I have guessed from his question tags! :) Thank you.

Comment: I did mention .Net Core in the question. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @kjwdamme **.NET Core** is not the same as **ASP.NET Core**.

Comment: @Imantas Yes! `.NET Core` is the runtime while` ASP.NET Core` is the framework. But most the people says that `.NET Core` framework! Actually this is wrong! Framework is `ASP.NET Core` on top of runtime `.NET Core`.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Thanks for clearing that up! will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataSeeder class and Inject DbContext in it. 
Write a seedData method to insert the required data.   This would be custom logic.

You can run this code after database is created.

```
public class DataSeeder
{
    public static void SeedRandomPassword(YourDbContext context)
    {
            //// your custom logic to generate random password 
            //// set it to right user


            context.Users.Add();  // Or Update depending on what you need
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```